# Optaplanner: How to get solver instance in Quarkus

Tags: quarkus, optaplanner

I am using Quarkus optaplanner, so instead of using SolverFactory to build a solver, I us ethe Quarkus way to inject a solverManager then let it solve the problem:

```
val solverJob: SolverJob<SolarDesign, UUID> = solverManager.solve(problemId, problem)
```

But I want to still be able to addEventListener like:

```
solver.addEventListener(SolverEventListener<SolarDesign>() {
            fun bestSolutionChanged(event: BestSolutionChangedEvent<MyProblem>) {
                val solution = event.getNewBestSolution()
                if (solution.score.isFeasible()) {
                    println("found new best solution")
                    println(solution)
                }
            }
        })
```

Question is how do I get a solver instance in Quarkus optaplanner so I can use it to addEventListener? It does not seem to be doable from solverManager.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following example shows how to obtain a `Solver` instance in Quarkus. The `SolverManager` API does not cover this option so the alternative approach is to inject a `SolverFactory`, use it to build a `Solver` instance and manage its lifecycle yourself.

The example also shows how to get access to the `Phase` lifecycle. It can be useful for experiments during development. However, that's only possible through casting the solver instance to `DefaultSolver`, which is an internal API. There are no backward compatibility guarantees on the internal classes. They can significantly change in future minor releases and cause compilation errors if you use them in your code. **Do not use it in production.**

```kotlin
class MySolverResource(private val solverFactory: SolverFactory<SolarDesign>) {

  fun solve(problemId : UUID) {
    // WARNING: DefaultSolver is OptaPlanner's internal class.
    // Backward compatibility is not guaranteed.
    // Its usage is totally not recommended.
    val solver: DefaultSolver<SolarDesign> = solverFactory.buildSolver() as DefaultSolver<SolarDesign>
    solver.addPhaseLifecycleListener(object : PhaseLifecycleListenerAdapter<SolarDesign>() {
      override fun stepEnded(stepScope: AbstractStepScope<SolarDesign>) {
        printSolution(stepScope.createOrGetClonedSolution())
      }
    })
    solver.solve(loadProblem(problemId))
  }

  fun printSolution(solution: SolarDesign) {}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is possible with `SolverManager` and you don't need to obtain a `Solver` instance.

Use `SolverManager.solverAndListen(problemId, problemFinder, bestSolutionConsumer)`. The third argument is a consumer where you can do whatever you want with each best solution that is found. It could look something like this in your case:

```kotlin
fun solve() {
    val solverJob: SolverJob<SolarDesign, UUID> = solverManager
        .solveAndListen(problemId, { problemId -> problem }, this::printSolution)
}

fun printSolution(solution: SolarDesign) {
    if (solution.score.isFeasible()) {
        println("found new best solution")
        println(solution)
    }
}
```

Find more details in this [section](https://www.optaplanner.org/docs/optaplanner/latest/planner-configuration/planner-configuration.html#solverManagerSolveAndListen) about `SolverManager`.

Comment: What if I want to listen to each stepEnd and print the result of the stepEnd?

Comment: See my second answer. I don't think printing the solution after each step is something that you want in production. Note that steps can even worsen the solution in some algorithms, which can be useful to escape local minima.

Comment: Thanks, this is not intended for production. I only want to for example print the solution at each stepEnd to check how it is being moved